# Find a sets $A$, $B$, $C$ and functions $f$, $g$, where $f: A\to B$ and $g: B\to C$ such that $(g\circ f): A\to C$ is a bijection.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Find a set $A$, a set $B$, and a set $C$, and a function $f$, and a function $g$, where $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B\rightarrow C$ such that $(g \circ  f): A\rightarrow C$ is a bijection and neither $f$ nor $g$ is a bijection.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I am completely lost to be honest, I am not sure if what Julien has is sufficient enough or if I need to prove the bijection.

Comment: I think that my professor said that f can't be injective, and g can't be surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $f$ should be injective and $g$ should be surjective.

$A=\{a\}$, $B=\{a,b\}$, and $C=\{a\}.$

$$f:A\to B; \quad f(a)=a$$
$$g:B\to C; \quad g(a)=g(b)=a$$

Comment: Can you please explain the parts of this please? For example, do you include that (g o f): A->C. thanks!

Comment: $g o f (a) = g(a)=a$.

Comment: Is f not injective and g not surjective?

Comment: $f$ should be injective and $g$ should be surjective, as they are.

Comment: so f is not surjective, and g is not injective, since neither f nor g can be a bijection?

Comment: Does that show that (g o f) is a bijection?

Comment: so since gof is identity, it is a bijection?

Comment: simply: bijection means: injective + surjective. can you see this in g o f (a) =a ?

Comment: I see why it's injective, could you just say why it is subjective, sorry.

Comment: By definition of *subjective*. in fact only elemnt of C is $a$. and there is an element that gof maps to it

Comment: you are welcome.