# Is this a correct example where $g ◦ f$ bijective, but $f$ and $g$ are not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've already seen an example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688896/find-a-sets-a-b-c-and-functions-f-g-where-f-a-to-b-and-g-b-to/1688901#1688901), that fit this description, but I just need clarification about whether or not this is correct with these domains/codomains.

$f: \{0\} → \{0, 1\}$

$g: \{0, 1\} → \{0\}$

$g ◦ f: \{0\} → \{0\}$

$f(0) = 0$, so the codomain $\{0, 1\}$ is not equal to the range $\{0\}$, meaning $f$ is not surjective and therefore is not bijective.

$g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 0$, so the function is not injective, meaning $g$ is therefore not bijective.

$g(f(0)) = g(0) = 0$, so the codomain $\{0\}$ is equal to the range $\{0\}$ and the function is one-to-one, meaning $g ◦ f$ is bijective.

Comment: Everything is fine.

Comment: Very good sir. Keep it up.

Comment: Yes. The domain of  $g f$, for any functions$ f,g,$ is Dom$(g)\cap \{f(x): x\in $Dom$(f)\}.$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. Well done.